# 415 Unsupported Media Type in RESTful webservice

Tags: java, rest

I have written a RESTful web service that returns a list o f words.
The class Word is annotated as the root element.

I tested this on rest client it generated 415 Unsupported MediaType.
Can anyone help what else has to be done to make it work.

```
@POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("getCategoryWordListFromJSON")
    public List<Word> getLearnWordListByCategory(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        List<Word> wordList = new ArrayList<Word>();
        try {
            String category = (String) jsonObject.get("category");
            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, category);
            LearnWordListDao wordListDao = new LearnWordListDaoImpl();
            wordList.addAll(wordListDao.getCategoryListFor(category));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, e.getMessage());
        }
        return wordList;
    }
```

Comment: Only Jettison based `JSONObject` is supported, not the json library's. Switch to the jettison `JSONObject` and try.

Comment: You should have the request header content type as `application/json`

Comment: How exactly do you call the webservice? Most likely your client doesn't send `Content-Type: application/json` header.

Comment: @sogeek I have set the content type as application/json

Comment: @Allwyn please see the answer. it should work for you. if it does work, please mark answer as correct so that others know.

Answer (score 2):

HiAllwyn,

There are many ways of returning of the List. Here it will not able to parse into the List object as provided in your code.
Please try this.... it works.... :)

```
@POST
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("getCategoryWordListFromJSON")
public Response getLearnWordListByCategory(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    List<Word> wordList = new ArrayList<Word>();
    try {
        String category = (String) jsonObject.get("category");
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, category);
        LearnWordListDao wordListDao = new LearnWordListDaoImpl();
        wordList.addAll(wordListDao.getCategoryListFor(category));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, e.getMessage());
    }


final GenericEntity<List<Word>> entity = new GenericEntity<List<Word>>(wordList) { };
       return Response.ok().entity(entity).build();

}
```

Comment: return Response.ok().entity(wordList.toArray(new Word[wordList.size()])).build();    is also one type...